# How can I fix "CSRF token missing" error?

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I'm building a web application with Django as my backend framework and DjangoRestFramework as webAPI, React Native as the frontend, and apisauce as an HTTP client. When I try to make a POST request from the frontend to the backend, I get this error :

> CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing

I don't get the error when I use postman.

Is it good if I comment this out `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` ?

Answer (score 0):

CSRF tokens are used to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks. This error implies that you are not providing CSRF in your POST request. I was wondering about your reason to use `apisauce` instead of `axios`, since axios automatic inclusion of the CSRF token.

Meaning you would not need to comment "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware"

and ensure that your app is CSRF attack free.

**EDIT:**

Ok, if you must use `apisauce`, you can manual set the csrf token using following code:

```
import apisauce from 'apisauce';

const api = apisauce.create({
  baseURL: 'https://yourbackend.com/api',
});

const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

api.setHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);

api.post('/endpoint', {
  data: 'yourdata',
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});

function getCookie(name) {
  // you may have to change this function a bit
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}
```

Comment: I am using apisauce because apisauce has a good way of handling errors

Comment: Please check the edit, if it's useful an upvote or tick is appreciated.

Comment: I have tried axios and am still getting the error